# Calculating winning team for each hole from individual scores

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing individual scores (golf) for each player per hole, per round (the full table contains many more scores for other players, groups, days, tournaments, etc.).

Here are the records from the first two holes of one round:

```
id, days_id, hole_id, strokes, points, net_strokes, par, pkey, course_id, players_id, balls_id, match_id, team_id, hole_no
3831, 54, 272, 5, 3, 4, 5, 11, 23, 16, 43, 11, 6, 1
3832, 54, 272, 6, 2, 5, 5, 11, 23, 3, 43, 11, 7, 1
3833, 54, 272, 5, 3, 4, 5, 11, 23, 15, 43, 11, 6, 1
3834, 54, 272, 7, 2, 5, 5, 11, 23, 22, 43, 11, 7, 1
3835, 54, 273, 5, 2, 4, 4, 7, 23, 16, 43, 11, 6, 2
3836, 54, 273, 4, 3, 3, 4, 7, 23, 3, 43, 11, 7, 2
3837, 54, 273, 6, 1, 5, 4, 7, 23, 15, 43, 11, 6, 2
3838, 54, 273, 6, 2, 4, 4, 7, 23, 22, 43, 11, 7, 2
```

The four players (16,3,15,22) belong to one of two teams (two players are in team 6 and the other two in team 7, in this case). The best score (highest value of "points") per hole of each team is used to determine the winner of the hole (or if it is a tie).

In this case for hole 1, Team 6 has two 3 points scores and Team 7 has two 2 points scores, so max(points) for Team 6 is 3 and max(points) for Team 7 is 2. Therefore, because 3 > 2 Team 6 wins the hole.

I run MySQL 5.7 and what I want is to output one row for each hole with the winning team_id. Like this:

```
match_id, hole_no, winning_team
11, 1, 6
11, 2, 7
```

If the teams get the same score on a hole I would want the winning_team value to be "0".

I can get something close with this query but it requires inputting parameters for the where clauses and also repeats the global max(points) value for each team and I don't know how to filter correctly.

```
select match_id,
       holeno, 
       a.pts as a_pts, 
       b.pts as b_pts, 
       round(ifnull((a.pts-b.pts)/abs(a.pts-b.pts),0),0) as diff 
from  ( 
        select max(xb.points) as pts 
        from strokes xb
        where xb.team_id =7 and xb.balls_id=43
     ) b,
    (   select max(xa.points) as pts 
        from strokes xa
        where xa.team_id =6 and xa.balls_id=43
    ) a,
       strokes c
left join holes on c.hole_id = holes.id
where c.team_id =6 
and c.balls_id=43 
group by holeno;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to sum the points for each hole. Then use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to sort and assign a ranking based on the highest score. Then grab the row with the highest score, i.e. row_number = 1.

```
WITH rankedScores AS (
  SELECT t.match_id
         , t.hole_no
         , t.team_id
         , t.total_points
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY t.hole_no 
            ORDER BY t.total_points DESC
         ) AS row_num
  FROM (
       SELECT  match_id, hole_no, team_id, SUM(points) AS total_points
       FROM    YourTable
       GROUP BY match_id, hole_no, team_id  
  ) t
)
SELECT h.match_id
       , h.hole_no
       , h.total_points
       , IF(h.total_points = sh.total_points, 0, h.team_id) AS team_id
FROM   rankedScores h LEFT JOIN rankedScores sh 
           ON h.match_id = sh.match_id
           AND h.hole_no = sh.hole_no
           AND h.row_num = 1
           AND sh.row_num = 2
WHERE  h.row_num = 1;
```

**Sample Data**

> ```
> hole_id | hole_no | players_id | match_id | team_id
> ------: | ------: | ---------: | -------: | ------:
>     272 |       1 |         16 |       11 |       6
>     272 |       1 |          3 |       11 |       7
>     272 |       1 |         15 |       11 |       6
>     272 |       1 |         22 |       11 |       7
>     273 |       2 |         16 |       11 |       6
>     273 |       2 |          3 |       11 |       7
>     273 |       2 |         15 |       11 |       6
>     273 |       2 |         22 |       11 |       7
>     272 |       3 |         16 |       11 |       6
>     272 |       3 |          3 |       11 |       7
>     272 |       3 |         15 |       11 |       6
>     272 |       3 |         22 |       11 |       7
>     273 |       4 |         16 |       11 |       6
>     273 |       4 |          3 |       11 |       7
>     273 |       4 |         15 |       11 |       6
>     273 |       4 |         22 |       11 |       7
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> match_id | hole_no | total_points | team_id
> -------: | ------: | -----------: | ------:
>       11 |       1 |            6 |       6
>       11 |       2 |            5 |       0
>       11 |       3 |            6 |       6
>       11 |       4 |            5 |       7
>       11 |       5 |            2 |       7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e887ccca3f61e9441f40e317b491c7e)*

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to do it in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: I would love to accept your answer but I am unable to test it in my environment.